# How do I know what caused a form submission?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<form name="myForm" id="a" action="/action_page.php"  method="post">
  Name: <input type="email" name="fname">
  

</form>
<button type="submit" form="a"  >submits</button>
<script>
const form=document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('a',e.currentTarget);
  console.log(e.target);  
},true);
</script>
```

e.target is 'form' itself  on clicking on the ***button*** whereas according to what I have understood it should be button.

I checked for other events like invalid and click,it works perfectly fine.
Is it because of some submitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't listening to the `click` event of the `button`, you are listening to the `submit` event of the `form`, that's why you see the `form` as `target` of the `Event`.

The submit event is not necessarily emitted on the submit button click, it could also be emitted by pressing <kbd>↲</kbd> in a form input field (but not on a programmatic submission: see [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit))

Luckily, what caused the form submission is available in the [`SubmitEvent.submitter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) property:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    console.log(e.submitter);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input placeholder="Type Enter here!">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Just another submit button</button>
</form>
```